# Segmetation fault error - Problema no código main para inserção de nodos em árvore binária

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa que lê registros e salva estes registros em uma lista encadeada e em uma árvore binária.

Entretanto, eu não estou conseguindo salvar os nodos na árvore binária, aparecendo um erro de segment fault error.

Eu gostaria de saber por que aparece este erro e como concerta-lo.

Aqui está meu arquivo main.c:

```
int main(){

registro p1_main;
lista   p2_main;
nodo p3_main;
int escolha1 = 99, escolha2;


criarLista(&p2_main);
cria_arvore(&p3_main);
do {
    printf("Qual opção a seguir você deseja realizar?\n\n1-Adicionar Contato\n2-Apresentar nomes registrados\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &escolha1);

switch(escolha1){
    case 1:
        criar_registro(&p1_main);
        insere_ini(&p2_main, &p1_main);
        CriarNodo(&p1_main);
        insere_Arvore(&p3_main, &p1_main);
    case 2:
        imprime_nomes(&p2_main);
    }
}
while ( escolha1 != 0);


return 0;

}
```

Aqui está a estrutura.h dos códigos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct registro_st{         // sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
} registro;

typedef struct nodo_st{
    registro *dado;
    struct nodo_st *dir;
    struct nodo_st *esq;
} nodo;

typedef struct Lista_st{
    nodo *cabeca;
    nodo *cauda;
    int tamanho;
} lista;

nodo* CriarNodo(registro * p){
        nodo* n;
        n = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        n->dado = p;
        n->dir = NULL;
        n->esq = NULL;
        return n;
}

void criarLista(lista *l){
    l->cauda = NULL;
    l->cabeca = NULL;
    l->tamanho = 0;
}



void insere_ini(lista *l, registro* dado){
    nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        if(novo == NULL){
            return 0; //falta de espaço
        };


        novo->dado = dado;
        novo->dir = l->cauda; //antigo primeiro aponta para o próximo
        l->cauda = novo;        // novo nodo recebe ponteiro para começo
        l->tamanho = l->tamanho + 1;
        printf("\n\nEsse foi o registro de num: %d.\n", l->tamanho);
        printf("\nnodo implementado!!\n");
        return novo;
}

nodo* raiz;

//FUNÇÕES PARA UTILIZAR NO MAIN

void imprime_nomes(lista *l){            // função que imprime os valores
        nodo* p = l->cauda;
            while(p)
            {                                           // Usando while, não é necessário estabelecer um loop para percorrer toda lista.
            printf("Login eh: %s\n", p->dado->login);
            printf("Nome eh: %s\n", p->dado->nome);
            p = p->dir;
            }
}

void criar_registro(registro *p){                   //função para adicionar os contatos
    printf("Qual login para registro:\n");
    scanf("%s", &p->login);
    printf("Qual o nome do contato:\n");
    scanf("%s", &p->nome);
    printf("Qual valor para registrar:\n");
    scanf("%f", &p->valor);
}

nodo* raiz; //porque um ponteiro para um ponteiro?

nodo* cria_arvore(){                            //função para criar árvore
    nodo* raiz = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    if(raiz != NULL)
        {
        return raiz;
        }
    }


void insere_Arvore(nodo **raiz, struct registro_st *registro)
{
    //o compilador faz sempre cast de void* para o tipo indicado, não sendo assim necessário
    nodo* novo = malloc(sizeof(nodo)); /*agora sem cast pois é desnecessário*/
    if(novo == NULL)
    {
        return; /* é void logo não pode ter tipo de retorno*/
    }

    novo->dado = registro; //o dado é o registro todo em si
    novo->dir = NULL;
    novo->esq= NULL;

    if(*raiz == NULL) //ver se o valor do ponteiro é null, logo arvore vazia
    {
        *raiz = novo;
        return;
    }

    nodo* atual = *raiz;
    nodo* ant = NULL;


    while(atual != NULL) //ciclo agora só para navegar até ao sitio correto
    {
        ant = atual;

        //o valor a ser inserido vem no próprio registro, com registro->valor
        if (registro->valor == atual->dado->valor)
        {
            free(novo);
            return; /* é void logo não pode ter tipo de retorno*/
        }

        if(registro->valor > atual->dado->valor)
        {
            atual = atual->dir;
        }
        else
        {
            atual = atual->esq;
        }
    }

    //após navegar é feita a inserção pelo no anterior.
    if (registro->valor > ant->dado->valor){ //se maior que o anterior fica a direita
        ant->dir = novo;
    }
    else { //senão fica a esquerda
        ant->esq = novo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tua utilização da arvore não está correta de acordo com a tua ultima pergunta que eu respondi. No teu `main` tens:

```
int main(){
   ...
   nodo p3_main;
```

Quando a arvore deve de ser um ponteiro, para funcionar com as funções criadas, assim como ter o valor de inicio de `NULL` como eu tinha exemplificado. Dessa forma deveria então ser:

```
int main(){
   ...
   nodo *p3_main = NULL; //agora com valor inicial de NULL
```

Repara que é bem importante que tenha este valor de inicio caso contrario quando for feita a navegação no ciclo ele nunca irá parar:

```
...
while(atual != NULL)
...
```

Assim como nunca saberá se a lista está vazia:

```
...
if(*raiz == NULL) //ver se o valor do ponteiro é null, logo arvore vazia
{
   ...
```

Também não é necessária a função `cria_arvore`, porque a função de inserção na arvore chamada `insere_Arvore` já contempla o facto de a arvore estar vazia e então cria o primeiro nó individualmente, aqui:

```
if(*raiz == NULL) //ver se o valor do ponteiro é null, logo arvore vazia
{
   *raiz = novo;
   return;
}
```

E a chamada ao `cria_arvore` deve ser retirada:

```
int main(){
   ...
   nodo *p3_main = NULL; //agora com valor inicial de NULL
   ...
   /*cria_arvore(&p3_main); //agora sem o cria_arvore pois não é necessário*/
```

E estas pequenas alterações já irão fazer o programa funcionar

Comment: Isac, eu pensava que eu precisava criar a árvore, igual como eu fiz com a lista encadeada, A função, realmente, já contempla este fato. Eu estou tendo bastante dificuldade na compreensão de ponteiros e estruturas, se souberes de algum material, link, pdf e etc e queiras deixar disponível aqui eu agradeço. No geral, muito obrigado pelo suporte que tens dado às minhas perguntas.

Comment: @Arduin O que não estas a visualizar é que a arvore é basicamente um conjunto de nós. Logo criar a arvore representa apenas criar o primeiro nó, que é algo que a função `insere_Arvore` já faz. É no entanto importante de mencionar que podia ser como tinhas feito, com uma função de criação do primeiro nó da arvore, mas para isso não era necessário o teste dentro da função `insere_Arvore`. Assim de cabeça não me vem à cabeça bom material de estudo, mas vou ver se vejo algum e logo indico.